# How do I find a set containing all components of some vector and all of the ways we can add the components?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, algorithms

Given some vector, I want to find the set containing

1. All possible sum's of the components of the vector
2. The individual vector components themselves.

For example, given the vector:

$
y = \left[\begin{array}{}
    a \\
    b \\
    c \\
    \end{array} \right]
    $

how can we find the set $\{a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c\}$?

And further, what is the general rule we can apply to an n-dimensional vector to get the same set?

Like

$
z = \left[\begin{array}{}
    a \\
    b \\
    \vdots \\
    n 
    \end{array} \right]
    $

Lastly, what is the name of the general rule?

(I'm trying to do this exact thing in Java, but I'm trying to find some general algorithm first)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you only care about pairwise sums? As in, do you care about the element $\{a+b+c\}$?

Comment: What about $a+a$ and its iterations?

Comment: And what if one of the entries is zero? Say, $a=0$ and $b=5$, would you want $5$ as an entry twice?

Comment: 1. "Say, a=0 and b=5, would you want 5 as an entry twice?" No, as you'd have a+b covered 2. "do you care about the element {a+b+c}" No. Only summations of 2 numbers 3. "What about a+a" a+a is not important to me.